# Use react-redux connect in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I try to build a react app in typescript using redux and react-router-dom. I ran into typing issues when I added redux to my app. Thus I created the following minimal example with only one page *test-page*:

**App.jsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import Test from './containers/test-page'
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ui container" id="main">
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/test" />}/>
        <Route exact path="/test" component={Test} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The container for the test page looks like this. It produces a typing error in the call to *connect*.

**containers/test-page/index.tsx**

```
import { Dispatch } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import TestPage from './test-page'

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Dispatch<any>) {
  return dispatch({ type: 'ALERT_USER' });
}

function mapStateToProps(state: any) {
  return { label: 'my test label' }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TestPage)
```

The container uses the following react component, which in production should render a page for the router. It produces two errors, see below.

**containers/test-page/test-page.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';

export namespace Test {
  export interface Props {
    alert: () => void;
    label: string;
  }

  export interface State {
  }
}

export default class TestPage extends React.Component {

  constructor(props?: Test.Props, state?: Test.State, context?: any) {
    super(props, context);
  }

  sendAlert = () => {
      this.props.alert()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <button onClick={this.sendAlert}>{this.props.label}</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

### Error messages:

```
proxyConsole.js:54 ./src/containers/test-page/test-page.tsx
(20,18): error TS2339: Property 'alert' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<{}>'.

proxyConsole.js:54 ./src/containers/test-page/test-page.tsx
(27,54): error TS2339: Property 'label' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<{}>'.

proxyConsole.js:54 ./src/containers/test-page/index.tsx
(16,3): error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof TestPage' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<{ label: string; } & { type: string; }>'.
  Type 'typeof TestPage' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<{ label: string; } & { type: string; }>'.
    Type 'typeof TestPage' provides no match for the signature '(props: { label: string; } & { type: string; } & { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any> | null'.
```

I tried to follow different guides and looked up example implementations but could not solve these issues. I do not understand the error messages of the typescript compiler:

- Why do my properties not exist on `this.props` when I defined them?
- What exactly is not assignable in connect?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A couple of things I notice:

1) As far as I've seen in examples and when working with `props` in TypeScript, your call to `React.Component` needs to specify `Props` as a type argument like so:

```
export default class TestPage extends React.Component<Test.Props, Test.State>{

    constructor(props: Test.Props) {
        super(props);
    }

}
```

You can specify that your component does not accept `props` or `state` by passing empty interfaces i.e.:

```
export default class TestPage extends React.Component<{}, {}>{

    // constructor becomes 'useless' at this point and is not needed
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

}
```

I think this explains why your call signature is not matching and why there are no properties visible on `this.props` - TS sees an interface of `ReadOnly{}` since it has no type arguments passed in.

2) Your `mapStateToProps` function doesn't look quite right. `mapStateToProps` takes two arguments, `state` (referencing your Redux `store`) and `ownProps` as an optional second argument, which refers to `props` passed down from the parent. So `mapStateToProps` should look like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state: any, ownProps: { label: string }) {

    return {
        label: ownProps.label
    };
}
```

This is my guess for why `connect` is throwing an error - it is simply a place where you make assertions about how Redux should handle combining `props` coming from the `store` and `props` coming from the parent. Let me know if this works out.

Answer (score 12):

This doesn't work because connect is a generic function. This means you need to provide additional type parameters.

```
connect<StateProps, DispatchProps>({
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
})(SomeComponent);
```

You can find typing implementation [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-redux/index.d.ts#L59). Everything you need to know is there C:

Answer (score 1):

Working syntax variant for Type Script application is:

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';

    interface ComponentProps {
    // Your properties here
    }

    interface ComponentState {
    // Your properties here
    }

    interface MapStateToPropsTypes {
    // Your properties here
    }

    interface MapDispatchToPropsTypes {
    // Your properties here
    }

    class MyComponentName extends React.Component<ComponentProps, ComponentState> {
        constructor(props: ComponentProps) {
            super(props);
        }
    }

    export default connect<MapStateToPropsTypes, MapDispatchToPropsTypes>(
      mapStateToProps,
      mapDispatchToProps)
    (MyComponentName)
```