# how to type react-redux connect in flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, flowtype

This is what my `mapStateToProps` looks like.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state): StateProps => {
    let status = false;
    if (state.productsPage.currentProduct) {
        if (state.productsPage.currentProduct.status === "ACTIVE") {
            status = true;
        }
    }
    return {
        showModal: state.productsPage.showModal,
        currentProduct: state.productsPage.currentProduct,
        isLoading: state.status.loading.PRODUCTS_EDIT,
        initialValues: {
            name: state.productsPage.currentProduct ? state.productsPage.currentProduct.name : "",
            status,
        },
    };
};
```

Here is the shape of `StateProps`

```
type StateProps = {
    showModal: boolean,
    currentProduct: Object,
    isLoading: boolean,
    initialValues: {
        name: string,
        status: boolean,
    }
}
```

This is my usage of connect.

```
const connected = connect<React$StatelessFunctionalComponent<any>, StateProps>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);
```

This produces the following error, and I have no idea what it means or how to go about solving it.

> [flow] Cannot call `connect` because property `currentProduct` is
>   missing in `React.StatelessFunctionalComponent` [1] in the indexer
>   property's key of type argument `ST`. (References: [1])

Comment: https://flow.org/en/docs/react/redux/

Answer (score 3):

It is recommended that you upgrade Flow to at least past 0.89, and use [Flow Typed's newest React Redux library definition](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/react-redux_v5.x.x/flow_v0.89.x-/react-redux_v5.x.x.js).

Then, you can annotate the connected components with `Props` and `OwnProps`

```
import * as React from 'react'

type OwnProps = {|
  passthrough: string,
  forMapStateToProps: string
|}

type Props = {|
  ...OwnProps,
  fromMapStateToProps: string,
  dispatch1: () => void
|}

const MyComponent = (props: Props) => (
  <div onClick={props.dispatch1}>
    {props.passthrough}
    {props.fromMapStateToProps}
  </div>
)

export default connect<Props, OwnProps, _, _, _, _>(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(MyComponent)
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/wgao19/dfec19df95230949c610d2cadf4a40d5) is a more detailed guide that includes a couple more use cases.

Answer (score 0):

`React$StatelessFunctionalComponent` is a generic that expects prop types. Instead of `<any>`, you would want the props that that function expects to receive -- most importantly, it expects to receive your `StateProps` returned by `mapStateToProps` (though it may expect others in addition).

It may change depending on version of `react-redux`, but I am seeing some documentation that suggests that the generics for `connect` are the return value of `mapStateToProps`, not a React element. - [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47105501/4856301)

You may be needing `connect<StateProps, DispatchPropsIfAny>` instead of providing an Element type.

Comment: not sure about the any vs prop types, you may be right about that will try soon, but the first argument in `connect` generics has to have a callable signature, at least in the version of react-redux flow typed I am using.